# Reading all files in a directory without a loop

Tags: python

I have been looking for days and was wondering if there is any way to read all the files in a directory in python without using a loop. The reason I ask is because when I go to write the files it goes through the loop again and overwrites all my information or doubles it when I only need to grab one file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - where are you reading/writing? If I were to guess, I think you might be using the same loop to read and write your files. I suggest you have one loop to read your files, do all the operations you need to do, and then another loop to write the files. Please post your code so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I love `pathlib` for such tasks

```
from pathlib import Path
# create a posix path object
folder_path = Path('/path/to/your/folder')
# iterate over directory and store filenames in a list
files_list = list(folder_path.iterdir())
# access file names
print(files_list[0].name)
```

always pretty handy